# How could I know which procedure printed the log in xcode?

Tags: xcode, logging

I'm getting a weird log from the console during the ios app running, just like:

```
2014-02-09 22:38:36.676 myappname[39747:70b] Stop!!
```

I've searched in my project for "Stop!!" but there's no result.
Does there a way I could know who printed it ?

PS.I'm using many libs and frameworks, like XMPPFramework, AFNetworking, SDWebImage and etc. Could these possibly the source?

Comment: _Could these possibly the source?_ since you've checked your sources ant not found the text, it seems rather probable that one of the frameworks you're pulling in is the responsible party. You may be able to use the "strings" command on the libraries / frameworks in order to find which contains this message.

Comment: You may overwrite NSLog with the same but with saying which method called it.

Comment: Thank you @mah. It's from libopenalmanager.a.

Answer (score 0):

I used linux "strings" command to all the .a file I've imported. It's libopenalmanager.a who printed it.

```
strings libopenalmanager.a |grep Stop
Stop!!
Stop!!
Stop!!
```

I'm curious about why this lib print a log like this.

Thank @mah for the help!